# Can unthinking entities be “informed” in the sense of “being provided with information”?

Tags: word-usage

In scientific papers, I read something along the lines of the following at times:

> Our results on banana transmogrifation may inform studies on apple transmogrification.

Given the context, I am pretty certain that this is intended to mean:

> Our results on banana transmogrifation may be provide (useful) information to people performing studies on apple transmogrification.

However, I never encountered *inform* in the sense of *to provide information to* applied to an object such as *studies,* that is neither a person nor an entity representing persons (such as *research groups* or *the government)* or similar and thus cannot actually digest information. The dictionaries I consulted<sup>[1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inform), [2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inform)</sup> neither explicitly excluded such a usage nor did they give examples for it.

As all such sentences may have been written by non-native speakers of English and been missed by the copy editor, I thus want to know **whether it is actually possible to use *inform* in this way** or whether this is usage is based on a mistranslation or similar.

I am aware that *inform* can be used with unthinking objects when used in the meaning of *to give an essential quality to* or similar, but this meaning would not make the sense in the contexts I am talking about – what is “informing” can not be regarded essential in most cases.

Comment: Google Books claims nearly 1000 written instances of things which may [*inform future studies*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inform+future+studies%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), and over 7000 that [*inform future research*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inform+future+research%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), so you might have a bit of a job convincing all of those writers that they're making a mistake.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You might as well turn that into an answer. I considered this unsearchable as I had not expected to find that many uses of that particular sentence alone.

Comment: As a native speaker I already knew what I expected to find in Google Books, obviously. You won't find many "prescriptivists" here on ELU willing to dispute the "validity" of constructions with even just dozens of instances in GB, let alone hundreds or thousands. It's potentially a very useful resource for you, but you need to choose search strings that will mostly reflect the *exact* usage you're wondering about (as opposed to different contexts, "accidental collocations", etc.). And keep an eye on the *dates* - some "obsolete" usages were once relatively common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You seem to want to solve a problem that does not exist – though I am not exactly certain what it is. Do you think that I want a prescriptivist answer?

Comment: Not at all - I just meant that Google Books is a perfectly reasonable way of establishing whether native speakers actually use a construction or not. And bear in mind the vast majority of native speakers learn almost nothing about usage by consulting reference books - we just replicate forms we hear/read others using, and extrapolate from those using "rules, principles" that we're often not even consciously aware of. Your cited usage sounds normal enough to me, but I've no intention of looking for any specific authority to back my position there. I think those Google Books results are enough.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I do not disagree with that, hence my suggestion to turn this into an answer. As I said, I did not even think about using a full-text search because I did not think I could weed out the specific usages I was looking for due to the inability to distinguish the nature of the object in an automatic search. I was wrong though, as a specific case sufficed.

Comment: Even though you obviously have pretty good command of English, I assume you're *not* a native speaker, or you probably wouldn't be asking about this. To be honest, I think it would probably be better asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where it's quite possible others who know more than me about the *reason* why you have/had doubts about the usage might be better able to address your concerns. (It could relate to some aspect of *German* usage that I don't know of, for example).

Comment: To be fair, I, a native speaker, was well into college before I ran across *inform* used this way, and it struck me as odd/wrong.  I've gotten used to it by now, but I still don't use it that way myself.

Answer (score 3):

Try [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inform) (sense 2 below):

> **inform** ...
>
> v.tr.
>
> 1. a. To impart information to; make aware of something: *We were informed by mail of the change in plans. The nurse informed me that*
>      *visiting hours were over.*
>
>    b. To acquaint (oneself) with knowledge of a subject.
> 2. a. To give form or character to; imbue with a quality or an essence: "A society's strength is measured by ... its ability to
>      inform a future generation with its moral standards" (Vanity Fair).
>
>    b.
>      To be a formative or characterizing presence in; animate: "It is this
>      brash, backroom sensibility that informs his work as a novelist" (Jeff
>      Shear)....

or RHK Webster's (at the same link):

> **inform** 3. to pervade or permeate with manifest effect: A love of nature informed his writing.

Comment: Oh, nice find in Webster!

Comment: *Inform with*, I have never seen that, but I suppose it makes sense!

Comment: I am sorry but I fail to see a big difference between the definitions you provided to the ones mentioned in the last pragaraph of my question: While *inform* in this meaning can be applied to unthinking objects, it also does not mean *provide information* anymore.

Comment: The 'inform' used in say 'informed future studies' [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=y5nTBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA661&lpg=PA661&dq=%22informed+future+studies%22&source=bl&ots=M58p8mWn2M&sig=x4VGmcoMcY8GYh8ZWZiYcJaeP0Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uNsyVfeJHtDkaKWKgJAB&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22informed%20future%20studies%22&f=false) means 'be a formative presence in', ie 'give rise to this sort of', 'direct', 'govern the structure of'. Another example: 'The data from the first study strongly informed future studies' {[FreshQuest](http://groups.ischool.berkeley.edu/ikids/freshquest/project.html)}.